# How to compute float array distance in java android

Tags: java, android

Insime my Android app, I have two float arrays and I want to compute the distance:

```
float[] arrayA;
float[] arrayB;
diff = ?
```

In **Python** I do:

```
diff = np.sum(abs(arrayA - arrayB))
```

I can't find the same operators in java.

Should I use a for loop? Or there are faster ways?

Comment: Are you sure you can subtract arrays in Python? By the way Python can do basically anything but it does it bad - it's probably not very efficient. I'd use a for loop. When you say faster, you mean faster to write or faster to execute?

Comment: Numpy is another story though. Anyway, I don't think there is such functionality out-of-the-box in Java (up to 8). You could try to make it work with streams, but my first thought would probably be going with a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code if you want to have it for each element:

```
float[] diff=new float[arrayA.length];//Assuming same length
for(int i=0;i<diff.length;i++){
   diff[i]=arrayA[i]-arrayB[i];
}
```

Or, if you only want one variable as result:

```
float[] diff=0;
for(int i=0;i<diff.length;i++){
   diff+=arrayA[i]-arrayB[i];
}
```